# How do I create a reference to a C++ object from a C style pointer of an absolute address

Tags: c++, casting, memory-address

We need to do a lot of operations on 8/16/32 bit (unsigned) integers stored in a complemented form.
For this we have a template integer class with operators, and 
from this we get multiple classes with signed and unsigned 8/16/32 contents.

I:E: `uint32_at`, `uint32_bt`, `int32_at`, `int32_bt` etc.
where each class instance has an internal variable `val` with the value.

We want to have constant arrays of such object, but if we define:

```
const uint32_bt table[4096] = { uint32_bt(5), uint32_bt(17), ... };
```

the compiler generates a constructor call for every element.
An efficient compiler would generate 4 x 4096 = 16,384 bytes of flash.
Our compiler generates about 100kB of flash and 16384 bytes of SRAM,
since it calls a constructor to create every element.

One idea is to generate the table in C, and then 
create a C++ class for the complete table.

```
const uint32_t CTable[4096] = { ... };
```

and then create an instance of the table class passing the pointer and the size.

```
CPP_Table Table(4096, CTable);
   This initiates two internal variables
   tab = CTable
   size = 4096
```

The index operator would then return an object which is just a reference to something in the C Table.

```
uint32B operator [] (
const uint32B& operator [] (const uint32_t index) const
{
    return (somekindofcast)(&tab[size - index]);
}
```

So the question is, how do I cast an address so I can return a reference to an object?

Comment: Couldn't you preallocate the whole array, get a raw pointer for the whole arena, and use some pointer math to cast whatever part you want?

Comment: What you want to do sounds like undefined behaviour (due to aliasing). There are ways around this. But a much simpler solution might be to make the constructor `constexpr` so it can be run at compile time, which should allow the compiler to write the data into flash storage.

Comment: `const uint32_bt table[4096] = { uint32_at(5)` ... of course that requires a conversion constructor. If you want an array of `uint32_bt`, initialize it with `uint32_bt(5)` not `uint32_at(5)`

Comment: Preallocating a table using uint32_t CTable[MAX] = ...  is what I think will work, but I don’t understand how to do the cast to return a pointer into the table as an object.

Comment: Post the definition of `uint32_bt`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const uint32_bt table[4096] = { uint32_at(5), uint32_at(17), ... };
> ```
>
> the compiler generates a constructor call for every element.

Make `uint32_at` constructor `constexpr`. And make it an array of `uint32_at`.

Comment: The uint32_bt table beeing initiated using uint32_at constructors was a mistake, so I edited the question.  I tried making the constructor ’constexpr’, but that did not result in a table in flash. All constructors are called in a large subroutine, and the table is stored in SRAM.